# Bessels inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

Why can you change the top index of sum in the last step of [this](http://planetmath.org/proofofbesselinequality) proof (see below) from $n$ to infinity ?

> Let  $r_n = x - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \langle x,e_k \rangle \cdot e_k$.
>
> Then for $j = 1,\dots,n,$
>
> \begin{align} \langle r_n,e_j \rangle &= \langle x,e_j \rangle - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \langle \langle x,e_k \rangle \cdot e_k, e_j \rangle \\
> &= \langle x,e_j \rangle - \langle x,e_j\rangle \langle e_j, e_j \rangle =0
> \end{align}
>
> so $e_1,\dots,e_n,r_n$ is an orthogonal series. Computing the norms, we see that
>
> $$\vert \vert x \vert \vert^2 = \Bigg \vert \Bigg \vert r_n + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \langle x, e_k \rangle \Bigg \vert \Bigg\vert^2 = \vert \vert r_n \vert \vert^2 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert \langle x,e_k \rangle \vert^2 \ge \sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert \langle x,e_k \rangle \vert^2.$$
>
> So the series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \vert \langle x,e_k \rangle \vert^2$$ Converges and is bounded by $\vert \vert x \vert \vert^2$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

It’s really just an application of a fact about convergent sequences. If $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a sequence of real numbers converging to a real number $x$, and $x_n\le C$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $x\le C$. Applying this to a convergent series $\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k$, we see that if $\sum_{k=1}^na_k\le C$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_k\le C$$

as well. In the proof of Bessel’s inequality $C=\|x\|^2$, and $a_k=|\langle x,e_k\rangle|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

According to the second to last line 
$\sum^n_{k=1}|\langle x,e_k \rangle|^2 \leq ||x||^2$

If this is true for all $n$ then the sequence of partial sums $\{s_n\}$ is bounded by $||x||^2$ where $s_n:=\sum^n_{k=1}|\langle x,e_k \rangle|^2$. Therefore the limit of this sequence must also be smaller than $||x||^2$, i.e. $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}|\langle x,e_k \rangle|^2 \leq ||x||^2$